# Smooth resizing of panels in SassMeister

Tags: javascript, css

I've been working with the [SassMeister](https://www.sassmeister.com/) app a lot recently and I'd like to know how they made the divider between the two panels work so smoothly. Is it possibly to achieve with just CSS and no JS? If anyone has any suggestions for something like this I'm very interested!